# Azure Pipline build steps related to Http Calls

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am creating a pipeline in Azure DevOps. Now I want to Integrate Http Get call in Azure Pipeline task.

If the response is 200/201 then other pipeline build step will perform or else no other pipeline task will perform.

Suggest me solution how to achieve this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops

Comment: My main concern is after reciving response if will prefoem pipeline task if desired response comes or else it will not perform any other tasks

Comment: Read what I sent. There's success criteria variables in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the Http Get in PowerShell, then according to the result set a variable, the other tasks will be depend on this variable. for example:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://test.com -Method Get
$statusCode = $response.StatusCode
if(($statusCode -eq 200) -or ($statusCode -eq 201))
{
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=status]ok"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvaraible variable=status]notOk"
}
```

Now, in the other tasks you can add a custom condition bases of the `status` variable:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['status'], 'ok'))
```

In yaml:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
     script: 'echo Test'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['status'], 'ok'))
```

In the editor:

[image]